# Incorrect way of creating new class in method

Tags: java, drawing

I have a subclass "DotsDraw" in a class "Game". The subclass should draw a 10*8 dot grid on a JPanel "areaImage". In a method of class Game, I'm creating the grid, see code below.

DotsDraw code:

```
private static class DotsDraw extends JPanel {
    private int x,xx,y,yy;
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    int xnum = 65, ynum = 65;   
    while (xnum<650)
    {
        while (ynum<780)
        {
            x = xnum-5;
            xx = xnum+5;
            y = ynum-5;
            yy = ynum+5;
            repaint();
            revalidate();
            ynum = ynum+65;
            super.paintComponent(g);  
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
            g.fillOval(x,y,xx,yy);
        }
        xnum=xnum+65;
    }            

    }
}
```

Method "gamePlay" where the grid is created:

```
@override
private void gamePlay ()
{
    readCoordinates();

    int xnum= 0; double sAnswer=0;
    while (xnum<8)
    {
        sAnswer = sAnswer + ((cnum[xnum]*cnum[xnum+3])-(cnum[xnum+1]*cnum[xnum+2]));
        xnum=xnum+2;
    }
    tAnswer = Math.abs(sAnswer/2);

    DotsDraw() dotGrid = new DotsDraw();
}
```

It says that a semicolon is expected after " DotsDraw()", what can be the problem?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: It says that a semi collum is expected after " DotsDraw()"

Comment: Edited, thnx for notifying :)

Answer (score 0):

Your variable declaration is wrong.

Change this:

```
DotsDraw() dotGrid = new DotsDraw();
```

to

```
DotsDraw dotGrid = new DotsDraw();
```

Comment: :) No error anymore, but somehow it doesnt draw. I forgot to put the drawing on a JPanel, any idea how to add it on a JPanel called areaImage that i mentioned?